# expect with exec and awk does nto show value

Tags: awk, tcl

When using expect to SET variable value using `exec` and `awk` doe snot throw error but also does not extract the value.

My snippet is as below

```
set routername    [lindex $argv 0]
set routerip "exec  awk {{ /$routername/print \$2 }} /tmp/RIPTable"

puts "router ip is : $routerip\n"
```

expecting the value of routerip to be `127.0.0.1` as this the IP for the name in the file.

The output seen is as below
`router ip is : exec  awk {{ /$routername/print \$2 }} /tmp/RIPTable`

What is wrong when set routerip?

Answer (score 3):

You should write like this:

```
set routerip [exec awk "/$routername/ { print \$2 }" /tmp/RIPTable]
```

Comment: it fails with cannot open file. `awk: can't open file /tmp/RIPTable` Permission on the file was initially 744, changed it to 777 to give a try but fails as above.

Comment: I'd pass the router name into awk with the `-v` option: that allows us to keep the non-interpolating quotes around the awk script body: `set routerip [exec awk -v "rname=$routername" {$0 ~ rname {print $2}} /tmp/RIPTable]`

Comment: @glennjackman i continue getting the same error. Unable to open the file with awk. `awk: can't open file /tmp/RIPTable
 source line number 1
    while executing
"exec awk -v "rname=$routername" { $0 ~ rname { print $2 }} /tmp/RIPTable"
    invoked from within
"set routerip [exec awk -v "rname=$routername" { $0 ~ rname { print $2 }} /tmp/RIPTable]"
    (file "./main.exp" line 80)`

Comment: This has nothing to do with expect. Does that file exist? Does your user have permission to read it?

Comment: permission is 777. file RIPTable file has entry as `asrip01  127.0.0.1   192.168.0.2  TEST
asrip02  127.0.0.1  192.168.0.11   STAGE`

Comment: @glennjackman any suggestion. i have spent couple hours .. but no luck.